# Selecting a Random list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

So I have 3 lists:

`a = []`
`b = ["a", "b", "c"]`
`c = ["d", "e", "f"]`

how can I randomly select either list b or c and import it into list a?

Thanks.

Comment: By import, do you mean copy contents of b or c to a?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `random.choice`:

```
import random

a = ['foo']
b = ['bar', 'quux']
c = ['spam', 'eggs']

a.extend(random.choice([b, c]))
```

`a` will end up being either `['foo', 'bar', 'quux']` or `['foo', 'spam', 'eggs']` .

Answer (score 2):

To get random elements from sequence objects such as lists (`list`), tuples (`tuple`), strings (`str`) in Python, use `choice()`, `sample()`, `choices()` of the `random` module.

The `choice()` method returns one random element, and the `sample()` and `choices()` methods return a list of multiple random elements. The `sample()` is used for random sampling without replacement, and `choices()` is used for random sampling with replacement.

The `random` method — Generate random numbers.

```py
import random
l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
print(random.choice(l))
```